# User entity with one to one relation has empty drop down

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster 4.13.3
In the jdl, I have the following relation.

```
relationship OneToOne {
    UserInfo{user(userName)} to User{userInfo}
}
```

UserInfo table has extra user detail and relates to other tables I have.

In the UI, I went to Entities -> User Info -> "Create new User info"

In this form, User input is present, but drop down is empty.  I was hoping to see admin, user and all new users there.

What is the simple way to link User and UserInfo from the UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  userName doesn't exist in User.  I replaced with login and it is working now.